# Tensorflow SavedModel method much larger than h5

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have saved the same model using multiple different formats, one using the standard model.save() which uses the SavedModel format from tensorflow and another with model.save('*.h5') which uses the hdf5 format.

When loading the model for inference the SavedModel file loads 1Gb into memory although the actual model on disc is only 5mb (the .pb file) and the variable/assets are only a few kb. But the h5 file is only ~50mb in memory.

I am really unsure why the SavedModel method would take so much memory and am looking for an answer. Is this method not usable?

Comment: The key difference between HDF5 (.h5 ) and SavedModel is that HDF5 uses object configs to save the model architecture, while SavedModel saves the execution graph. Thus, SavedModels are able to save custom objects like subclassed models and custom layers without requiring the original code. For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#saving_custom_objects)